# UIScrollView not responding in xcode8, ios10 when it was OK in Xcode 7 ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios10, xcode8

Inside my app, I have a UIViewController which is composed of the following elements:

1. Two buttons and a UILabel on the top part of it
2. A UISCrollView which contains different elements, UILabels, Buttons and more.

I include a screenshot for you to understand the structure.

[image: Screenshot of IB]

When compiled in Xcode 7 with iOS 9 SDK everything has been working properly. But now I am trying to update the app for it to work in iOS 10 and the screen does not respond when trying to scroll. The two buttons outside the UIScrollView still are working OK.

The only warning I am receiving when running on the iPhone is:
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "",
    ""
)

IB also tells me that there is a mistake with the constraints (red indicator). It tells that ScrollVertical (UISCrollView) need constraints for: Y position or Height. But I'm quite sure that this message was shown in xcode7-ios9, when everything worked properly.

Any idea what is happening? Any idea would be appreciated, since I have been struggling with this for a day.

This arre the constraints expanded:

[image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should expend the `Constraints` node in your view hierarchy, and capture the constraints your have defined in Xcode, and paste it here. That would be helped for issue tracking.

Comment: OK, I have included the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but with a twist.  On first startup  of subscreen scrolling won't work. After rotating the device it works fine. It makes no difference if it starts on portrait or landscape oritation. after a rotating the app works fine. No problems with IOS9 and IOS8.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ApDetailTableViewController.h"
#import "ApMailViewController.h"
#import "ApApplicatieData.h"
#import "ztatz_constants.h"
#import "ztatz_macro.h"

@interface ApDetailTableViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentUIView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *apUIScrolView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewHeightConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *lastSeperatorView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *applicatienaam;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *san;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *beschrijving;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *updatetime;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *afdelingsnaam;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *contactpersoon;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *email;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *controledatum;

@end

@implementation ApDetailTableViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.applicatienaam.text = self.apDataForDetails.applicatienaam;
    self.san.text = self.apDataForDetails.san;
    self.beschrijving.text = self.apDataForDetails.beschrijving;
    self.status.text = self.apDataForDetails.status;
    self.updatetime.text = self.apDataForDetails.updatetime;
    self.afdelingsnaam.text = self.apDataForDetails.afdelingsnaam;
    self.contactpersoon.text=self.apDataForDetails.contactpersoon;
    self.email.text=self.apDataForDetails.email;
    self.controledatum.text=self.apDataForDetails.controledatum;

    // start a top of scroll view
   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}





-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    // limit the slack space at the end of the scroll view.
    DLog(@"y = %f\n", self.lastSeperatorView.frame.origin.y);
    self.contentViewHeightConstraint.constant =                self.lastSeperatorView.frame.origin.y+4;

}

@end
```